# How to append a matrix element by element?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Consider if I have some matrices constructed as such:

```
A = {
  { {} , {} },
  { {} , {} }
    }
B = {
  { a , b },
  { c , d }
    }
C = {
  { e , f },
  { g , h }
    }
...
```

`A` serves as a matrix of empty lists. I want to be able to append `B`, `C`, etc. to `A`, to obtain a final matrix like

```
A = {
  { {a, e, ...} , {b, f, ...} },
  { {c, g, ...} , {d, h, ...} }
    }
```

How can I do this? My matrices are always square and of the same dimensions. An alternative which could also be useful is to `Join` two matrices element by element, if the matrix elements of both are already lists.

Comment: You wrote "My matrices are always square and of the same dimensions". That is not true. Try `Dimensions/@{A,B}`

Comment: Kai, with `A` and `B` as inputs what is the desired result: `{{{a}, {b}}, {{c}, {d}}}` or `{{{{}, a}, {{}, b}}, {{{}, c}, {{}, d}}}`?

Comment: @Fortsaint my meaning is that the matrices which are being appended are always the same dimension. Matrix `A` is simply a matrix of empty lists to append to.

Comment: @kglr see the update

Comment: with `A = {{{}, {}}, {{}, {}}};B = {{a, b}, {c, d}};cc = {{e, f}, {g, h}};` if you use `Transpose[{A, B, cc}, {3, 1, 2}]` you get `{{{{}, a, e}, {{}, b, f}}, {{{}, c, g}, {{}, d, h}}}`. But your post says you want `{{{a, e}, {b, f}}, {{c, g}, {d, h}}}`, no?

Comment: @kglr simply omitting the `A` is fine, I was initially thinking I wanted to append directly, but making a list of matrices and then transposing it achieves the same result. `A` is not necessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have 4 matrices:

```
SeedRandom[1]
{a, b, c, d} = RandomInteger[1, {4, 2, 2}];
```

Then, you can use [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose) to construct the desired matrix:

```
Transpose[{a, b, c, d}, {3, 1, 2}]
```

> {{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}}

Comment: I think `Transpose[{a, b, c, d}, {3, 1, 2}]` may be enough.

Comment: @Roman Thanks, much simpler!

Comment: I'm still wrapping my head around the second argument of transpose, but this looks like the simplest way for me to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 7):

To join nested arrays elementwise, use the third argument of `Join`. For matrices, depth 1 (default) is rows, 2 is columns, and 3 is elements.

```
a = Array[{}&, {2,2}];

b = {
{b1, b2},
{b3, b4}
};

listEach = Map[List, #, {2}]&

appendEach[x_,y_] := Join[x, listEach[y], 3]

Print[appendEach[appendEach[a, b], b+5]]
(* {{{b1, 5 + b1}, {b2, 5 + b2}}, {{b3, 5 + b3}, {b4, 5 + b4}}} *)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY2xCsJADED3fEVA6GIWW12UDg5dRMH9CCVXCz2wtdQbWo779jMdhG4vyXukF9@1vXjXSEqCJV6nSRYTYkYYcsojXwCs7gMEeyC0eSSlQukYIerx7b6@kqZT5yGjuetIuFvryBmAjGM7vFbBzDUtNeO5xNvHDWYm/LdmYcKCAZ6TG7zZNFvUn6rZ/Yk5pR8)

However, if you are appending many matrices it may be more efficient to create a list of matrices using `Sow / Reap`, then `Transpose` into a matrix of lists.

Comment: What is the function of the `&` in the first line?

Comment: It's the syntax for a [pure function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).

Comment: right but there's no argument so I'm confused what it does

Comment: `{}&` takes no arguments and returns an empty list. The & is there because Array needs to be passed a function.

Comment: I see, this is the equivalent of `ConstantArray[{},{2,2}]` then?

Comment: Yes, I forgot ConstantArray existed.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1 = MapThread[List, #, 2] &;
f2 = Flatten[#, {{2}, {3}}] &;
```

Using Carl's example setup:

```
SeedRandom[1]
{a, b, c, d} = RandomInteger[1, {4, 2, 2}];

f1[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> {{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0}}}

```
f2[{a, b, c, d}] == f1[{a, b, c, d}] == Transpose[{a, b, c, d}, {3, 1, 2}]
```

> True

If some input matrices might have `{}` as an element all methods above retain `{}`s in the combined matrix:

```
f1[{a, A, c, d}]
```

> {{{1, {}, 0, 0}, {1, {}, 1, 0}}, {{0, {}, 0, 0}, {1, {}, 0, 0}}}

`MapThread` with `Flatten[{##}] &` as the first argument eliminates `{}`s:

```
MapThread[Flatten[{##}] &, {a, A, c, d}, 2]
```

> {{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}

**Original answer:**

[`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) at [`Level`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) 2:

```
MapThread[Flatten[{##}] &, {A, B}, 2]
```

> {{{a}, {b}}, {{c}, {d}}}